# How to resolve ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Other such posts didn't solve my error. I followed [this post](http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2012/7/24/Getting-Started-with-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-in-Python) to install **virtualenv** and **virtualenvwrapper** . Now when try running mkvirtualenv Addon-Tests in my project's root directory, I get an **error : ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path** 
*I followed all other such questions but none of them solved it.*

I had added this to my .bashrc file as instructed in that blog

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I use Ubuntu operating system.

Comment: Which version of python do you use? It seems that virtualenv has not been installed properly. There should be an executable in `/usr/bin/virtualenv`. This can be checked by running `which virtualenv` from bash.

Comment: Yes executing which command it shows nothing. actually I had got some exceptions while installing it.
Can you please tell me how to delete it and reinstall it? 
because I can't reinstall it without removing previous one..

Comment: `pip uninstall virtualenv` should do it. You might have to use `sudo` as well, depending on which OS you are using.

Comment: Hey thanks man.. That soled my problem.. :)